# How to do this set operation

Tags: matrices

Given, {A,B,C}  {D,E}  {X,Y,Z}

I want the following result:
•   {A,D,X}
•   {A,D,Y}
•   {A,D,Z}
•   {A,E,X}
•   {A,E,Y}
•   {A,E,Z}
•   {B,D,X}
•   {B,D,Y}
•   {B,D,Z}
•   {B,E,X}
•   {B,E,Y}
•   {B,E,Z}
•   {C,D,X}
•   {C,D,Y}
•   {C,D,Z}
•   {C,E,X}
•   {C,E,Y}
•   {C,E,Z}

Can you please point me to the set operator which does this? I am also trying to find the algorithm for the above, given "n" number of Sets with varying number of values in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of three sets:

$$
\{A, B, C\} \times \{D, E\} \times \{X, Y, Z\}
$$

For a discussion of algorithms, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741364/efficient-cartesian-product-algorithm) on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks. that exactly what I was looking for.